# One Select Radio button using multiple radio buttons on RecyclerView

Tags: android

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StateViewHolder stateViewHolder, int i) {
            GetStateApiResponse getStateApiResponse = state.get(i);
        stateViewHolder.btnstate.setText(getStateApiResponse.getStateName().toString());
        stateViewHolder.disttCount.setText(getStateApiResponse.getCount().toString());

       stateViewHolder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

               RadioButton checked_rb = group.findViewById(checkedId);

               if (lastChecked != null) {
                   lastChecked.setChecked(false);
               }
               //store the clicked radiobutton
               lastChecked = checked_rb;
           }
       });
```

}

this code is not working corrently on recyclerview if I clicked on radio button than automatically unchecked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is because `lastChecked` is an instance variable and holds the state of all of your list items. You can solve this problem by specifying a `lastChecked` variable for each of your items in the list.

Comment: items is not fixed

Answer (score 3):

correct answer of this question

```
private RadioButton lastChecked
...
    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StateViewHolder stateViewHolder, int i) {
                GetStateApiResponse getStateApiResponse = state.get(i);
            stateViewHolder.btnstate.setText(getStateApiResponse.getStateName().toString());
            stateViewHolder.disttCount.setText(getStateApiResponse.getCount().toString());


            if (lastChecked!=null && lastCheckedPos!=-1 && i==lastCheckedPos)
            {
                lastChecked.setChecked(true);
            }
            else
            {
                stateViewHolder.btnstate.setChecked(false);
            }



            stateViewHolder.btnstate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    for(GetStateApiResponse tempModel: state)
                        tempModel.setSetchecked(false);

                    state.get(i).setSetchecked(true);
                    lastCheckedPos=i;

                    if(null != lastChecked && !v.equals(lastChecked))
                        lastChecked.setChecked(false);
                    lastChecked = (RadioButton) v;
                    lastChecked.setChecked(true);


                }
            });


        }
```